# inheritance - TypeError: transform() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Tags: python, inheritance, scikit-learn

I'm trying to understand how inheritances work so I tried something really simple :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

class addition(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def fit(self, X,y=None):
        return self
    
    def transform(self, X, y):
        return X+y

class additionChild(addition, BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

test = additionChild(name='c\'est un text')
test.fit_transform(2,2)
```

But I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Untitled-3 in 
----> 181 test.fit_transform(X=2,y=2)

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    691         else:
    692             # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)
--> 693             return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)
    694 
    695 

TypeError: transform() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

which I don't understand because I specified the `y` argument.

Maybe it's somethig stupid but I can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: You are calling `fit_transform`, not `transform`. It is not evident from the question how `transform` is called.

Comment: I know but this is the error I get. I edited my post with the entire error message, maybe it will be more clear this way.

Comment: Apparently the `sklearn` framework expects the `transform` method to only have one argument. In this case it is wrong to define it with two arguments.

Comment: If your goal is to learn how inheritance works you should use an example that is *actually* simple and doesn't involve another framework.

Comment: Thank. I removed the y and it works. I wanted to understand how it works in order to do inheritance with `BaseEstimator` and `TransformerMixin` actually, but yes you're right I should start with something simpler.